# Group multiple charts with react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, bar-chart, react-chartjs-2

[image]

I want to create a dynamic chart similar to above image with [react-chartjs-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2). Basic problem definition is Grouping multiple charts with same base axis. Each bar in chart have its label (all charts have similar) and each chart have its title (or a label considering base axis).
I am confused how do I prepare the `dataset`?

Example data for chart:

```
[{
    "name": "overdue",
    "total": 33,
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"N",
            "count":7
        },
        {
            "name":"E",
            "count":10
        },
        {
            "name":"C",
            "count":3
        },
        {
            "name":"L",
            "count":13
        },
        {
            "name":"H",
            "count":18
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "inprogress",
    "total": 43,
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"N",
            "count":16
        },
        {
            "name":"E",
            "count":12
        },
        {
            "name":"C",
            "count":7
        },
        {
            "name":"L",
            "count":9
        },
        {
            "name":"H",
            "count":9
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "comingup",
    "total": 54,
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"N",
            "count":23
        },
        {
            "name":"E",
            "count":13
        },
        {
            "name":"C",
            "count":17
        },
        {
            "name":"L",
            "count":1
        },
        {
            "name":"H",
            "count":17
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "nodue",
    "total": 43,
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"N",
            "count":16
        },
        {
            "name":"E",
            "count":12
        },
        {
            "name":"C",
            "count":7
        },
        {
            "name":"L",
            "count":9
        },
        {
            "name":"H",
            "count":9
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "completed",
    "total": 54,
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"N",
            "count":23
        },
        {
            "name":"E",
            "count":13
        },
        {
            "name":"C",
            "count":17
        },
        {
            "name":"L",
            "count":1
        },
        {
            "name":"H",
            "count":17
        }
    ]
}]
```

I just want to know how I can form these data to chart like the image. Also, the if anyone can help with the design of bar that would be very helpful.
Thanks.